# Can I have a subclass of a subclass? How do I inherit the characteristics of the parent and those of another subclass without errors?

Tags: c++, inheritance

So below is some code I'm practicing inheritance with, I create an employee class, and a few subclasses under it. they all go as expected individually, but when I have *Lawyer* and *harvardLawyer*, I'd like for *harvardLawyer* to have a different constructor (deferent constructor variables, hours, salary, etc.) than *Lawyer*, but keep everything else (in this case, just the `sue()` method) the same.

Now instead of copying that method, I'd like to inherit it. I've tried multiple ways.

After a few edits...

> error: no matching constructor for initialization of
>         'lawyer'

How do I solve this?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;

class employee {
private:
    int baseHours = 40;
    double baseSalary = 40000.0;
    int baseVacationDays = 10;
    string baseVacationForm = "yellow";

public:
    employee(int hours = 40, double salary = 40000.0, int days = 10,
             string form = "yellow") {
        baseHours = hours;
        baseSalary = salary;
        baseVacationDays = days;
        baseVacationForm = form;
    }

    int getHours() { return baseHours; }
};

class lawyer : public employee {
public:
    lawyer() : employee(80, 30000.0, 15, "pink") {}

    string sue() { return "I'll see you in court!"; }
};

class harvardLawyer : public lawyer {
public:
    harvardLawyer() : lawyer(80, 36000.0, 18, "pink pink pink pink") {}
};

int main() {
    lawyer c;
    harvardLawyer d;
    cout << c.getHours() << "\n" << d.getHours() << "\n"; //<<d.sue();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @John so for example if I use multiple inheritance and create a main function where I call a variable of type harvardLawyer, then I use the getHours() method on it, I get the error 

non-static member 'getHours' found in multiple
      base-class subobjects of type 'employee':


    class harvardLawyer -> class employee
    class harvardLawyer -> class lawyer -> class employee

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `harvardLawyer` constructor, you attempt to invoke the `lawyer(int, double, int, string)` constructor. However, your `lawyer` class only has a `lawyer()` constructor. You're trying to call a function that doesn't exist.

To fix your immediate problem, you should modify your `lawyer` constructor to take all the parameters you're trying to pass into it. You can still specify default parameters - this allows you to call your constructor with zero, one, two, three, or four parameters (in the order shown). Your choice.

```
class lawyer : public employee {
public:
    lawyer(int hours = 80,
           double salary = 30000.0,
           int days = 15,
           string tag = "pink") : employee(hours, salary, days, tag) {}

    string sue() { return "I'll see you in court!"; }
};

class harvardLawyer : public lawyer {
public:
    harvardLawyer() : lawyer(80, 36000.0, 18, "pink pink pink pink") {}
};
```

---

However, it's not quite clear why you need a `harvardLawyer` class at all. If you want a `harvardLawyer`, just create a `lawyer` and pass the appropriate parameters. Assuming `harvardLaywer` is no longer a class:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    lawyer regular_lawyer = lawyer();
    lawyer harvard_lawyer = lawyer(80, 36000.0, 18, "pink pink pink pink");
    std::cout << harvard_lawyer.sue() << "\n";
}
```

Comment: So that useless data in the lawyer constructor wasn't actually there to start with, originally that line was just `lawyer():employee(80,30000.0,15,"pink")`

Comment: Now at that point everything works fine, but if I uncomment d.sue() (can be seen in the code in the question) , I get an error saying no member named 'sue' in 'harvardLawyer' as if it hadn't been inherited from the employee class

Comment: Well regardless of what used to be there or not, what's the interface you WANT to have? There are several ways to do this but it depends on what you want the external interface to look like. Again, I think `lawyer` should probably just have a `string` member called "university" or something to differentiate a `lawyer` from a `harvardLawyer`.

Comment: That wonky constructor in Lawyer along with `class harvardLawyer : public employee, public lawyer` was me trying to find a solution to the error I just mentioned above. I've changed it in the original question so you can better see how it was before that happened

Comment: @Jad if `harvardLawyer` only inherits from `employee` then it won't have `sue`. `sue` comes from `lawyer`.

Comment: @John so the way it currently runs based off the code in the question, all that's missing is I can't get the harvardLawyer class to inherit the sue() (or anything for that matter) from Lawyer, it only inherets from the employee parent class, so I need to find a way ti also inherit from the Lawyer class in a way that doesn't cause any errors

Comment: @Jad - you need to have `harvardLawyer` *only* inherit from `lawyer`. Not from `lawyer` AND `employee`.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Essentially the same answer I left to John, I'm trying to find a way to get one subclass to inherit characteristics of another subclass, while also inheriting from the parent at the same time

Comment: @Jad if `harvardLawyer` inherits from `lawyer` it will inherit all characteristics of `lawyer` and any of `lawyer`'s base classes, including `employee`.

Comment: @TedLyngmo It probably looks like too much trouble in this case because there's only one method I'm trying to inherit, but I'm picturing an example where maybe the Lawyer class has a lot more than that one method, and harvardLawyer needs all of those methods, along with the parent methods, but also needs to be its own subclass because a harvardLawyer object has a different base salary, base number of holidays, etc. then a regular lawyer

Comment: @Jad if a `harvardLawyer` needs different `salary`, `holidays`, etc, then you can simply modify the `lawyer` constructor to use the parameters passed into it, and send it different parameters.

Comment: @John if I have HarvardLawyer be a subclass of only Lawyer I end up getting **error: no matching constructor for initialization of
      'lawyer'**

Comment: What `lawyer` constructor are you calling and what does your `lawyer` constructor look like? This code is changing from minute to minute so bear with me here.

Comment: I figure I need to have harvardLawyer only inherit from lawyer, but I'd need to fix the constructor to stop getting the above error, but I'm not sure how

Comment: @John, I've just edited the original question another time to help you with that. What you should see if you look at it now is harvardLawyer being a subclass of only Lawyer, not employee, that code exactly gives me the constructor error I mentioned above that I'm not sure how to solve. I'm hoping if I get passed that then the sue() method would be inherited too.

Answer (score 1):

You need to reuse the constructor of the base class. The only constructor you have in the `lawyer` class does not match any constructor that `harvardLawyer` tries to use. In older versions of C++ you had to make proxy constructors to achieve the same effect but now a simple `using <base-class>::<constructor>` will do.

It brings in *all* constructors. Handy!

```
class lawyer : public employee {
public:
    using employee::employee;  //  <-  like so

    lawyer() : employee(80, 30000.0, 15, "pink") {}

    string sue() { return "I'll see you in court!"; }
};
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/b-vBNa)

Comment: It looks like you have the right idea, I hadn't thought of it that way, but it seems that you can't use the **using** declaration on constructors

**error: using declaration cannot refer to a constructor
        using employee::employee;**

Comment: @JadMoussa Added demo - i only added `using employee::employee;` to your code.

Comment: That's weird, the demo worked for me too. Could it be the compiler I'm using?

Comment: @JadMoussa Could be, but if so, you could be using a pre c++11 compiler (unusual Today, but happens).